# Why does command after `||` execute even if prior command succeeds?

Tags: bash, operators

I am using short-circuit evaluation (with `&&` and `||`) in a bash function,
and I don't understand the behavior I'm seeing.  I want the function to return
if the first number is not greater than the second:

```sh
[[ 5 > 2 ]] && echo true || echo false && return

#    ^             ^                   ^
# true so       do this        not this && this


[[ 5 > 8 ]] && echo true || echo false && return

#    ^             ^                   ^ 
# false so   don't do this      do this && this
```

but the function returns in either case. 
Why does the `return` command execute regardless of the first command's status?

Instead of `return` I have tried `break`,
but it doesn't work due to not being within a loop.

1. **Why does `return` seem to execute in both these cases?**
2. How else can I end a running function?

Comment: Why don't you just use `if` and `else` so the meaning will be clear?

Comment: [precedence of the shell logical operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/precedence-of-the-shell-logical-operators)

Comment: I was looking for a solution that used the current format, sorry should've specified that.. But I was also really curious to how the command always seemed to make it to the `return` command, regardless of truthiness..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    stmt1  &&  stmt2    ||  stmt3    &&  stmt4
```

is evaluated as

```
( ( stmt1  &&  stmt2 )  ||  stmt3 )  &&  stmt4
```

i.e., left to right.

So the logic is

```
Execute stmt1
If it succeeds,
then
    execute stmt2
endif
If stmt1 succeeds and stmt2 succeeds,
then
    (do nothing here)
else                    # i.e., if stmt1 fails,  OR  stmt1 succeeds and then stmt2 fails
    execute stmt3
endif
If stmt1 succeeds and stmt2 succeeds,
                  OR  stmt3 succeeds,
then
    execute stmt4
endif
```

Since `stmt2` and `stmt3`
are both `echo` statements, they both always succeed,
and so `stmt4` (the `return` statement)
is always executed.

I suspect you were expecting

```
( stmt1  &&  stmt2 )  ||  ( stmt3  &&  stmt4 )
```

and you can get that behavior (in general) by typing parentheses,
just like that:

```
 ( [[ 5 > N ]] && echo true )  ||  ( echo false && return )         # No, don’t do this
```

or braces:

```
{ [[ 5 > N ]] && echo true; }  ||  { echo false && return; }
```

Note that you ***must*** have whitespace after a `{`
and a semicolon before a `}`.

Note also that, with parentheses, the commands run in subshells,
whereas with braces, they don’t (they run in the main shell context). 
**In your specific code example, you must use braces**
(at least for the part after the `||`),
**because `return` doesn’t have any effect if it’s run in a subshell.**

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Most importantly thank you for breaking this down for me, it is really appreciated.

Comment: Actually, there are some rare cases where `echo` can fail (e.g. stdout is messed up and can't be written to), and in these cases the logic here will behave in still different unexpected ways. That's why you should use `if then else` instead -- it does what you expect without all these silly complications and confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Use `if` instead of logical operators.

```
if [[ 5 > 8 ]]
then echo true
else
    echo false
    return
fi
```

See [precedence of the shell logical operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/precedence-of-the-shell-logical-operators) for an explanation of how the operators combine.

Comment: Thank you for this Barmar.. this, my brain understands 100% of the time. Thank you for the reference too, I will study up.

Comment: @mar627 Programming patterns your brain understands are better than those it doesn't. That and the reasons I mentioned in my comment to the other answer are why `if then else` is a much better way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: But the other answer *does* answer the question of why the original code behaves as it does.